# Create new column from factor column by multiple conditions

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, gsub, grepl

I would like to create a new column from an existing column containing several factors, but where part of the factor names reoccur. Let me illustrate:

```
factorA <- c("paul173643738","paul827484","george39585496","george7848658946","john2354674","john346","ringo384934","ringo24653")
df <- data.frame(factorA)
```

This is my attempt:

```
library(dplyr)
    df <- mutate(
           df,factorB = case_when(
           matches(factorA,"paul.") ~ "paul",
           matches(factorA,"george.") ~ "george",
           matches(factorA,"john.") ~ "john",
           matches(factorA,"ringo.") ~ "ringo",
           TRUE ~ "NA"))
```

Which gives me `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: is_string(match) is not TRUE.` I assume that this is the result of me not specifying correctly how `R` is supposed to look for the string fragments I want.

The result should look like this:

```
           factorA  factorB
1    paul173643738  paul
2       paul827484  paul 
3   george39585496  george
4 george7848658946  george
5      john2354674  john
6          john346  john
7      ringo384934  ringo
8       ringo24653  ringo
```

I'm sure that this question has been asked before, but I can't find any answers to suit my needs. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the format "{name}{numbers}" is fixed? If so, you could use regex to extract the names.

Comment: why do you want to use factor variables? I only use them when needed.

Comment: `matches` is a select helper, you're using it in a wrong place, see `?select_helpers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stringr::str_detect`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
factorA <- c("paul173643738","paul827484","george39585496","george7848658946","john2354674","john346","ringo384934","ringo24653")
df <- as_data_frame(factorA)
df %>% 
  mutate(factorB = case_when(
    str_detect(factorA, "paul") ~ "paul",
    str_detect(factorA, "george") ~ "george",
    str_detect(factorA, "john") ~ "john",
    str_detect(factorA, "ringo") ~ "ringo"
  ))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#>   value            factorB
#>   <chr>            <chr>  
#> 1 paul173643738    paul   
#> 2 paul827484       paul   
#> 3 george39585496   george 
#> 4 george7848658946 george 
#> 5 john2354674      john   
#> 6 john346          john   
#> 7 ringo384934      ringo  
#> 8 ringo24653       ringo
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
mutate(factorB = case_when(
str_detect(factorA, 'paul') ~ 'paul',
str_detect(factorA,"paul.") ~ "paul",
str_detect(factorA,"george.") ~ "george",
str_detect(factorA,"john.") ~ "john",
str_detect(factorA,"ringo.") ~ "ringo"
))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string format specified in the `factorA` is fixed, you could extract the names using `gsub`:

```
only_names <- gsub('(^[A-Za-z]*).*', '\\1', factorA)
```

Answer (score 1):

using R base `sub` with regex

```
> data.frame(factorA, factor8=sub("\\d+", "", factorA))
           factorA factor8
1    paul173643738    paul
2       paul827484    paul
3   george39585496  george
4 george7848658946  george
5      john2354674    john
6          john346    john
7      ringo384934   ringo
8       ringo24653   ringo
```

Comment: or `gsub("\\d","",factorA)`

Answer (score 0):

Try `extract` and a regular expression that just detects the letters.

```
my.regex <- "([a-z]+)"

df %>% 
  extract(factorA, 
          into = "factorB", 
          regex = my.regex,
          remove = FALSE)

#>            factorA factorB
#> 1    paul173643738    paul
#> 2       paul827484    paul
#> 3   george39585496  george
#> 4 george7848658946  george
#> 5      john2354674    john
#> 6          john346    john
#> 7      ringo384934   ringo
#> 8       ringo24653   ringo
```

Usually, I'd be after cleaner data, though, with discrete values and names....

````
 my.regex <- "([a-z]+)([0-9]+)"        

  df %>% 
  extract(factorA, 
          into = c("factorA", "factorB"), 
          regex = my.regex,
          remove = FALSE)

#>   factorA    factorB
#> 1    paul  173643738
#> 2    paul     827484
#> 3  george   39585496
#> 4  george 7848658946
#> 5    john    2354674
#> 6    john        346
#> 7   ringo     384934
#> 8   ringo      24653
```
````

Created on 2018-07-28 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).